# How can I make a model get spawned right next to me in roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a dummy spawner for my gun testing game but I cant get it to spawn next to the player

I tried to use this but it just gives me an error saying "attempt to index number with 'Character'"

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function(player)
    local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local pos = char:GetPrimaryPartCFrame().p
    local clone = script.Parent.Dummy:Clone()
    clone.Parent = game.Workspace
    clone:MoveTo(pos)
end)
```

Comment: Is this a Script or a LocalScript?

Comment: I used a Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.MouseButton1Down` event returns the X and Y screen coordinate in pixels, not the player
as specified in the [api reference](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/GuiButton/MouseButton1Down)

thus doing `5.Character` causes an error

now for your problem

assuming this is a localscript

```lua
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local pos = char:GetPrimaryPartCFrame().p
    local clone = script.Parent.Dummy:Clone()
    clone.Parent = game.Workspace
    clone:MoveTo(pos)
end)
```

Comment: It was a Normal Script but I put it in a  localscript and it worked just fine thanks a lot!

Comment: Be aware that spawning objects in LocalScripts will make them only appear to _that_ player. If you want everyone to see the part, the spawning logic must happen on the server with a Script. But that can easily be accomplished with RemoteEvents.